# Create personalized Google Forms automatically from a Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a personalised form using a Google Apps script, but couldn't find the way in the documentation. For example, the for a different user the questions would be:

- Describe a "tree"
- Describe a "mountain"
- Describe a "river"

... and so on

Is this possible with Google Apps Script?

Comment: Your question is probably too vague to get anything else than a 'yes we can !' we all know that it has been quite successful in the past but it's not very useful in this forum...  That said, I do confirm megabyte1024 answer : YES   ;-)

Comment: @Gootyfer.. do you mean create a form as in a Form that captures data and stores it to a spreadsheet? One that can be sent via email, similar to http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/ ?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. Sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. Sorry for that.
I wanted to know if it's possible to create a Google Form (http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/), not from the user interface but programmatically from a script. I want to do this in order to create personalized surveys, or randomly generated surveys. 
For example, in a course of 20 students I want to ask Peter a question about a random colleague. Therefore, in order to create the question "What do you think about xx_Random_colleague_xx?", I want to do it from a script instead of creating 20 forms in the forms UI.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in 2014, yes, you can make a dynamic form:

There are three places where you change the form.

1. You can create several standard forms in advance and serve out a different form to each different user, or group of users:
   First make the first form. Then make a script that mails this form to the users you want, then iterate through all the items and replace the text. (See code at bottom of this post)
2. You can create a standard form, then replace certain text each time before serving the form. This can be done with the **onOpen()** trigger.

Note: It could be that this does not work as documented. I was not able to use this method, and the onOpen() was working only for opening the document FOR EDITING not for FILLING. 
I don't want to go into this too deeply, but it seems contrary to the documentation, which states that the OPEN-FOR-EDITING limitation applies only to the installable trigger and not oto the simple trigger.

1. After each user submits the form, in an installed trigger that runs the setQuiz() function, the trigger is set to act ON SUBMIT. 
   Each time a user submits a response, replace the texts as in #1 above. This works, BUT, if the next user clicks before the function completed replacing all texts in the form, the next user may get parts of the form before they were replaced!!

Not a very good idea.

Here's the code for the first solution (and the third)

```
  function setQuiz(keyword, replacement){
    var keyword = ...
    var replacement = ...
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var items = form.getItems();
    var txt;
    for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        txt = items[i].getTitle();
        txt = txt.replace(replacement, keyword);
        items[i].setTitle(txt);
        txt = "";
        txt = items[i].getHelpText();
        txt = txt.replace(replacement, keyword);
        items[i].setHelpText(txt);
     }
     return form;
     // CREATE A COPY of the form
     // and send email with link to the form's COPY in next method, which will be done, only after this method replaced all texts. (see issue with solution 3)
     // note you'll have to iterate between the replacement texts each time. So if you start out with tree to mountain, you must remember to change mountain to river...
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is in the comments. A little bit detailed answer is

1. Create a spreadsheet. Fill a pair of columns there like the following

> ```
> user1@email.com      tree
> user2@email.com      mountain
> user3@email.com      river
> ```

1. In your script: open the spreadsheet, read a range containing the filled columns to an array. Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet)
2. In your script: get the user email using the `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` function, find the email in the array.
3. In your script: create your form with a label. The label text should be something like `label.setText('Describe a "' + usersWord + '"');`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. Sorry for that.I wanted to know if it's possible to create a Google Form (google.com/google-d-s/forms), not from the user interface but programmatically from a script. I want to do this in order to create personalized surveys, or randomly generated surveys. For example, in a course of 20 students I want to ask Peter a question about a random colleague. Therefore, in order to create the question "What do you think about xx_Random_colleague_xx?", I want to do it from a script instead of creating 20 forms in the forms UI. Is it possible?

Comment: @gootyfer. Now the Google Forms are not supported by GAS. You can submit a feature request to the [GAS issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply!